# How to apply light theme for the activity and keep the dark theme for the dialogs at the same time?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog, android-theme

Is there a way that I could apply a custom style for an PreferenceActivity, which will inherit from Theme.Sherlock.Light or Theme.Light and keep the dark style for the preferenceDialog and AlertDialogs? Can I easily exclude dialogs from applying light style? if no which attributes should I set and what are the parameters of the default colors used in dividers, text active, inactive, titles and subtitles etc. in light theme? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by changing the activity theme to light and then I set programmatically the theme of the alert dialog to the one of the dark, built in android styles:

```
this.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
```

Since PreferenceDialog inherits from Dialog it also set this theme to all PreferenceDialogs.
To be more specific and add a style to a particular dialog you can use ContextThemeWrapper as used in Dialog.java in android source:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog))
```